# Custom uitabeviewcells blank when scrolling

Tags: core-data, uitableview, ios7, magicalrecord, afnetworking-2

I have two custom `UITableViewCells` I am trying to populate from an array that I am pulling from `CoreData` using `MagicalRecord`. The first three rows of data appear (the cells that are initially visible when the view loads) but when I scroll none of the cells below have any data populated into them. Also, when I scroll up the cells that initially displayed data are now blank. So it seems to be happening when any cell gets reused. I have been racking my brain and coming up empty on all my attempts to solve the problem. Here is my`cellForRowAtIndexPath` code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Explore *explore = [self.exploreCellData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

if ([explore.belief_id isEqualToString:@"0"]) {

    ExploreVoteCell *cell = (ExploreVoteCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ExploreVote" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.topicTitle setText:[explore topic_title]];
    [cell.votesCount setText:[explore calc_totalVotes]];
    [cell.timeDayCount setText:[explore day_difference]];
    return cell;

} else {

    ExploreBeliefCell *cell = (ExploreBeliefCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ExploreBelief" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.topicTitle setText:[explore topic_title]];
    return cell;        
}}
```

When I count the number of records in the array (for the number of rows) or `NSLog` some data elements when the table view loads the data is there. However, when I scroll the `NSLog` I set up inside the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath` method starts returning a null value once the scroll needs to start reusing cells.

I am new to using both `MagicalRecords` and `AFNetworking` so perhaps I am not be handling those correctly. Here is how I am pulling the data from CoreData into my `NSMutableArray`

```
- (void) fetchData {

self.exploreCellData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[Explore MR_findAllSortedBy:@"calc_totalVotes" ascending:YES]];}
```

Any help be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try using :
     [tableView registerClass:[YOURCUSTOMCELL class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CUSTOMIDENTIFIER"];

in forexample viewDidLoad 
and in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ListCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CUSTOMIDENTIFIER"];

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I am already running through that code in the CellForRowAtIndexPath code I put in above... any other ideas?